# Angular NG0200 - Circular dependency error but no warning

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency

The project I'm working on has started to throw an NG0200 runtime error indicating there is a circular dependency present in a service I am injecting:

```
ERROR Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for UserDetailsService. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0200
Angular 15
UserDetailsComponent_Factory user-details.component.ts:11
Angular 5
ProfileComponent_Template profile.component.html:7
Angular 43
RxJS 5
Angular 8
nrWrapper settings:4
promise callback*__nr_require<[12]</</< settings:4
Angular 9
webpackJsonpCallback jsonp chunk loading:77
<anonymous> ******_settings_profile_profile_module_ts.js:2
Angular 14
RxJS 5
Angular 8
nrWrapper settings:4
(Async: promise callback)
__nr_require<[12]</</< settings:4
Angular 9
webpackJsonpCallback jsonp chunk loading:77
<anonymous> ******_settings_profile_profile_module_ts.js:2
```

The url they provide has a helpful video showing that warnings will also be thrown to indicate which file are circularly dependent. I get no such warnings in my terminal or console, which I'm assuming is because the `--show-circular-dependencies` is deprecated. Even when I use the deprecated option it does not detect anything.

All SO questions I have found have answer suggesting the use of the warnings I'm not getting, or tools like `madge --circular path/to/my/project` which also does not detect anything.

Am I missing something about how to enable the warnings or detect these circular dependencies more explicitly?

Comment: Facing same issue, any fix?